# Moderator dashboard is not protected against post-overflow of text

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

We have seen the issue of text overflowing to the right, especially with long and unbroken strings of characters, many times on normal posts and comments, and it's been resolved for both of those.

It seems this is not the case on the dashboard. While it doesn't break when looking at the post in the question, the post on the moderator dashboard had the text extend well past the right sidebar.

No screenshot, because I instantly obliterated the offending answer on account of it being entirely noise.

Comment: Sounds like you're not using **Opera**

Comment: @random, do you actually use Opera?

Comment: There's always someone that is part of that 2%. And this time, it's not about money. @jjn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two large spams, a bucket of troll wings, a medium rage quit and one piece of freshly baked `word-wrap: break-word;` coming up*.

Will that be all?

<sub>* next build, as usual :)</sub>

Comment: I'll take a question in an answer-sized cup as well, thank you.

Comment: @GraceNote: Those are out; may I suggest an edit instead?

Comment: Fool! You should have asked for a shirt. Or some company stock. @gra